Trying to implement cursor-based zoom on Infinite Canvas in Swift
I'm trying to implement zooming like in Apple Maps in an infinite canvas app. Here's my code:
import SwiftUI

struct CanvasView: View {
    var imageName: String
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var isPinching: Bool = false
    @GestureState private var magnifyBy: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var lastScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var pinchLocation: CGPoint = .zero

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                if let _ = Bundle.main.path(forResource: imageName, ofType: "jpg") {
                    Image(imageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .clipShape(Rectangle())
                        .scaleEffect(scale * magnifyBy)
                        .offset(offset)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    if !isPinching {
                                        var newOffset = lastOffset
                                        newOffset.width += value.translation.width
                                        newOffset.height += value.translation.height
                                        offset = newOffset
                                        print("Drag - New Offset: \(newOffset)")
                                    }
                                }
                                .onEnded { _ in
                                    lastOffset = offset
                                    print("Drag Ended - Last Offset: \(lastOffset)")
                                }
                        )
                        .gesture(
                            MagnificationGesture()
                                .updating($magnifyBy) { value, state, _ in
                                    state = value
                                    print("Magnifying - Current magnifyBy: \(value), Pinch Location: \(pinchLocation)")
                                }
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    isPinching = true
                                    print("Pinch Changed - Scale: \(scale), MagnifyBy: \(value), Pinch Location: \(pinchLocation)")
                                }
                                .onEnded { value in
                                    isPinching = false
                                    scale *= value
                                    scale = min(max(scale, 1), 4)
                                    lastScale = scale
                                    lastOffset = offset
                                    print("Pinch Ended - New Scale: \(scale), Last Scale: \(lastScale), Final Pinch Location: \(pinchLocation)")
                                }
                        )
                        .simultaneousGesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    pinchLocation = value.location
                                    if isPinching {
                                        let newScale = scale * magnifyBy
                                        print("Simultaneous Gesture - Pinch Location: \(pinchLocation), New Scale: \(newScale)")
                                        offset = CanvasView.calculateNewOffset(
                                            for: pinchLocation,
                                            oldScale: lastScale,
                                            newScale: newScale,
                                            oldOffset: lastOffset
                                        )
                                        print("Simultaneous Gesture - New Offset: \(offset)")
                                    }
                                }
                                .onEnded { _ in
                                    lastOffset = offset
                                    print("Simultaneous Gesture Ended - Last Offset: \(lastOffset), Final Pinch Location: \(pinchLocation)")
                                }
                        )
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: resetZoom) {
                        Text("Reset Zoom")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    static func calculateNewOffset(
        for location: CGPoint,
        oldScale: CGFloat,
        newScale: CGFloat,
        oldOffset: CGSize
    ) -> CGSize {
        // Calculate the point we're zooming on in the coordinate space of the content
        let zoomPoint = CGPoint(
            x: (location.x + oldOffset.width) / oldScale,
            y: (location.y + oldOffset.height) / oldScale
        )
        
        // Calculate the new offset
        let newOffset = CGSize(
            width: zoomPoint.x * newScale - location.x,
            height: zoomPoint.y * newScale - location.y
        )
        
        print("Calculating New Offset:")
        print("  Pinch Location: \(location)")
        print("  Old Scale: \(oldScale), New Scale: \(newScale)")
        print("  Old Offset: \(oldOffset)")
        print("  Zoom Point: \(zoomPoint)")
        print("  Calculated New Offset: \(newOffset)")
        
        return newOffset
    }

    private func resetZoom() {
        scale = 1.0
        offset = .zero
        lastOffset = .zero
        lastScale = 1.0
        pinchLocation = .zero
        print("Reset Zoom - Scale: \(scale), Offset: \(offset), Last Offset: \(lastOffset), Last Scale: \(lastScale), Pinch Location: \(pinchLocation)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CanvasView(imageName: "AppleMaps")
    }
}

Currently, the view always zooms down to the right hand corner; now where the cursor is.
